# Compare elements of two lists and delete specific elements of the lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists like this:

```
list1 = [[1, 0.5] [2, 0.8] [3, 0.9] [4, 0.8] [5, 0.7]]
list2 = [1, 2, 5]
```

Now I want to compare every first element of `list1` with `list2` and if the first element of `list1` isn't in `list2` the whole element should be deleted.

The result of my example must be:

```
result = [[1, 0.5] [2, 0.8] [5, 0.7]]
```

I tried different `for` and `while` loops but it doesn't work.
It would be nice if someone can help me with a code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am actually unable to understand your intention. If you want to obtain your result in a new variable, go for the first answer. If you want to change `list1` in place by deleting elements, my answer will do.

```
list1 = [[1, 0.5], [2, 0.8], [3, 0.9], [4, 0.8], [5, 0.7]]
list2 = [1, 2, 5]
i = 0
while i < len(list1):
    if list1[i][0] not in list2:
        del list1[i]
        continue
    i += 1
print(f'{list1 = }')
```

Output:

```
list1 = [[1, 0.5], [2, 0.8], [5, 0.7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension for this:

```
result = [i for i in list1 if i[0] in list2]
```

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers work fine, but you can make it a little more efficient if you're working with larger cases by assuming both lists are in an increasing order:

```
list1 = [[1, 0.5], [2, 0.8], [3, 0.9], [4, 0.8], [5, 0.7]]
list2 = [1, 2, 5]

result = []
i = 0
j = 0
while (i < len(list1) and j < len(list2)):
    val1 = list1[i][0]
    val2 = list2[j]
    if (val1 == val2):
        result.append(list1[i])
        i += 1
        j += 1
    elif (val1 < val2):
        i += 1
    else:
        j += 1

print(result)
# [[1, 0.5], [2, 0.8], [5, 0.7]]
```